# BibTeX with XeLaTeX using TeX Live 2015

Tags: bibtex, xetex, article

I am trying to compile an `article` using `XeLaTeX`. The article also contain a `bibliography` file, which I want to print inside the article, without citing any of the bib entry.

Please see below the complete tex code-

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}                       %for loading fonts
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip}   %other packages for formatting
\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[big]{layaureo}              %better formatting of the A4 page
\usepackage{supertabular}               %for Grades
\usepackage{titlesec}                   %custom \section

%FONTS
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[
SmallCapsFont = Fontin-SmallCaps.otf,
BoldFont = Fontin-Bold.otf,
ItalicFont = Fontin-Italic.otf
]
{Fontin.otf}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{publications.bib}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty} % non-numbered pages

\font\fb=''[cmr10]'' %for use with \LaTeX command

\section{Section before Publications}
Section before Publications

\section{Publications}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\section{Section after Publications}
Section after Publications
\end{document}
```

To compile this code, I initially run `XeLaTeX` followed by `BibTeX`. The `BibTeX` reports following error-

```
Process started


This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015) The top-level auxiliary file: sample.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file sample.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file sample.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file sample.aux (There were 3 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)
```

Below is the necessary detail-

- Tex Live 2015
- Texmaker 4.5

I don't see the bib entries in the generated article. What's wrong here?

Comment: What if you load `biblatex` with the `backend=bibtex` option i.e. `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}`?

Comment: @DaiBowen: Awesome. It works perfectly. Can you please write down it as an answer, also describing the cause of the error?

Comment: Remove `\font\fb=''[cmr10]''`: it is syntactically wrong and is useless anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) package has support for two backends for processing/extracting entries from the `bib` file, `bibtex` and `biber` although `bibtex` is only supported for a subset of the possible [`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) functions detailed in *3.14 Using the fallback BibTeX backend* of the [`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) documentation.

By default the preferred backend of `biber` is expected when [`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) is loaded and thus different information is written to the `aux` file, incompatible with the necessary code for `bibtex`.  In order to run `bibtex` with [`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) the package call must explicitly say that `bibtex` will be used by passing the `backend=bibtex` option to [`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) i.e. `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}` if no other options are called.